# How do I ditch combat mechanics?

Tags: gm-techniques, combat, freeform

How can I run combat encounters with the least amount of combat mechanics, while still keeping my players engaged?

I'm very intentional with my GM-ing choices, and combat-mechanics as an extended conflict-resolution system have not earned their way into my game. I'm always trying to simplify my games so that I can keep the game running, and so that I can keep the players engaged with what's happening.

I'd love to run combat no differently than how other skill checks are played: loose, quick, and every roll being meaningful and having impact on the narrative. I want to keep my players from entering a slug-fest where each side throws punches until the other side goes down. There are many ways to do this, but I'm specifically exploring how it can be done by simplifying combat down to a few turning-points/rolls.

The reference articles that incited this question:

- [How to Run Fun Combat in a Stand-and-Deliver System](https://mythcreants.com/blog/how-to-run-fun-combat-in-a-stand-and-deliver-system/)
- [The Challenge of RPG Combat](https://mythcreants.com/blog/blog-series/the-challenge-of-rpg-combat/)

These articles somewhat answer this question, but they leave a lot open for interpretation. That's why I'm asking here.

### Clarification

I love combat scenes in my games, and so do my players. None of us really care for *"you deal 4 points of damage to the goblin, are you doing anything with your bonus action?"* when the real source of our fun is from kicking ass the way we imaging our character to kick ass *"wow, that was an amazing combat roll. You're holding the line against all 10 goblins while the party proceeds to..."*

We also love failure in our rolls, because it usually gives someone else the opportunity to step-up and have a turn at being a badass, too.

With some additional deep-dive thought, I think that few of my players actually *like* combat in D&D. I'm pretty sure they all like other aspects that combat introduces. Out of all my ~8 active players across 2 groups, I think only one player actually likes combat for combat's sake. 1 group unanimously likes working together in epic combat scenes. My other group has a variety of backgrounds (wargammers, D&D enthusiasts, rules-lawyer, power-gamers, etc), but they all like other aspects stemming from the combat. Some like the dungeon-crawl goals of killing, looting, and improving. I think that even the rules-lawyer doesn't care that much about combat. I think they're just hurt, and have a deep-rooted need to maintain control/agency, which they can do via exploiting and calling out all the rules-as-written. I think only the one player likes combat to see all the interactions play out: the damage types, resistances, critical/fumble table rolls, counterspelling a counterspell, effects of being prone+grappled+blind+swallowed+unconscious+exhausted, etc.

I've run Dungeon World PBtA, FATE, and simple/rules-light systems among others, but I was raised on D&D. I now play a bastardized version of FUDGE/FATE. Characters in my games are defined by their attributes, skills, and role-play.

---

A confession: I've actually run a one-shot in this way. However, this is still new to me, and I'm still exploring this method.

I think this style mostly comes down to communicating with your players and knowing their in-game intentions at all times. This is how I deal with non-combat moments, where I'm always doing a round table for everyone to narrate, act, or reveal their actions and thoughts. I often subconsciously do this in combat as well, where I do a round table to make sure I adjudicate everyone's actions in accordance to what they're expecting and wanting.

---

EDIT: I overhauled this question to be of value on SE. I posted the original on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/kso53s/how_do_i_ditch_combat_mechanics/).

Comment: Are you asking for an ad hoc game system - which is I think too broad in scope for our site - or for someone's homebrew system that worked the way you want it to?  I am not sure what kind of game/action/decision currency you are using to make choices and decisions have consequences

Comment: @gatherer818 thanks, I took the tour, and I found out that this question is definitely not suitable for Stack Exchange. This question is about running games rather than a specific question about a rule or system. It is definitely prone to subjective, opinion-based, discussion-like answers.

Comment: @Someone_Evil as written, it is an intriguing question but I think that my first read through of it left me with a "too broad" feeling (which descriptive of course we no longer have access to) but I was not a close voter. The last paragraph looks like "and I have an answer already" ... I suspect that leads to some of the CV: confusion?  FWIW: it's way too long for the core question, which is: *I am going to run LMOP with an alternate system and (named) and I need help with how to ditch combat mechanics*  -  Some of the background is very useful (previous experience) but it needs liposuction

Comment: Using my special powers to clarifying something: closed is temporary and reversible (see: [What does it mean for a question to be closed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11165)) and you can [edit] the question to clarify, add detail, or trim down the question as required. And we much prefer that to deleting and reposting (and it's a very interesting question many of us would like to see tackled).

Comment: @Someone_Evil I shortened it, and rearranged it to keep the pertinent question-essential information up top. Hopefully this is better?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I still feel like it's just looking for general advice. There isn't really a concrete question at the heart of it that can have a "best" or "correct" answer.

Comment: I VTR'd because "what is the least amount of engaging combat mechanics" is a concrete question and I might not have a best answer but I have a pretty state-of-the-art one.